# Device prefers weaker wifi6 connection over stronger wifi5

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I'm running Windows 11 on laptop that has "Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter". The modem router has Wi-Fi 6 capability but it is located 2 stories below where the laptop is and placed inside a rack cabinet. In order to increase coverage and signal strength, I installed an idle router that has capability running as an access point connected to router via switch, but it is Wi-Fi 5. Unlike other devices on the same floor eg. smartphone or smart room temperature controller, the laptop persists connecting to the router. There is no problem with AP for assigning ip addresses as other devices successfully connect through it and DHCP server is a smart switch.

I **tried** resetting, uninstalling, reinstalling the wireless adapter; uninstalling, reinstalling manufacturer's driver; configuring, uninstalling Killer software. None of them worked. Using Netsetman I'm able to monitor all wifi broadcasts within the building, which all have the **same SSID**, that includes router's and APs' and able to chose one to connect however, device persists connecting back to router instantly.

**Solution:** Both blocking laptop by its MAC address in router's wireless traffic and decreasing router's wireless signal strength to 25% worked independently. However these solutions might create problems in some situations as I roam with my laptop within the building or want to fully benefit wifi6 feature with my smartphone, for example.

Can anyone **help** with configuring laptop to prefer stronger connections over newer technology?

Comment: Maybe the Wi-Fi 5 AP can be set up to use a separate SSID (in addition to the original one).